# Eliminating a variable using three equations

Tags: linear-algebra

Given positive numbers $r$, $q$ $k$ and $N$ satisfying

$$\frac{1}{r} + \frac{N-1}{2q} = \frac{1}{2}- \frac{kN}{2}$$
and
$$R = \frac{2(1+k)r}{r-1}$$ and $$Q=\frac{2(1+k)q}{q-1},$$
I want to show that
$$\frac{1}{R} + \frac{N-1}{2Q} = \frac{N}{4}.$$

I tried for a long time and i couldn't show it. I wonder if it's even true. Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Did you already try to disprove it by choosing numbers that satisfy the first three equations  and insert  them in the fourth equation?

Comment: It is true, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is true!

Inserting the given equations for $R$ and $Q$ into your final equation we get:

$$\frac{1}{\frac{2(1+k)r}{r-1}} + \frac{N-1}{4\frac{(1+k)q}{q-1}} \stackrel{?}{=} \frac{N}{4} \leftrightarrow$$ $$\frac{2(r-1)}{r} +\frac{(N-1)(q-1)}{q}\stackrel{?}{=}N(1+k) \leftrightarrow$$
$$1- \frac{2}{r}+\frac{1}{q}+N(1-\frac{1}{q}-1-k)\stackrel{?}{=}0 \leftrightarrow$$
$$N \left( k+\frac{1}{q} \right)\stackrel{?}{=}1+\frac{1}{q}-\frac{2}{r}$$

Starting from the other end, with the first equation, we get:

$$\frac{N}{q}-\frac{1}{q}+kN +\frac{2}{r}-1 = 0 \leftrightarrow$$

$$N \left( k+\frac{1}{q} \right)=1+\frac{1}{q}-\frac{2}{r}$$

which is exactly the same as before!

Comment: Thanks for trying.. I am also thinking maybe it's not true. ANyway let me wait a while to see if someone figures it out.

Comment: Hey I think it does hold. You made a missstake in your fifth displayed equation!!

Comment: @25Chars I don't see it, could you point out where you think I made a mistake? And either way, the equation is still underdetermined.

Comment: @Lovsovs You didn't make a mistake sorry but your final diusplayed equation implies the first equation in the OP. Subtract $1$ on both sides, divide by $q$, rearrange and divide by $2$!

Comment: @25Chars Yes of course it can be rewritten this way; that was my starting point! This unfortunately doesn't show anything new.

Comment: @Lovsovs You started with the final displayed equation in the OP and plugged in $R$ and $Q$, no? THen in fact you proved that the final displayed equation in the OP holds IFF the first displayed equation in the OP holds.

Comment: @25Chars No, I also used the first equation to isolate $\frac{N-1}{q}$

Comment: @Lovsovs I don't see the problem. You yourself wrote "your final equation is only true if.." and you write a statement which is true, by assumption in the OP.

Comment: @25Chars You made be right, I will edit my answer when I have worked it out from scratch. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Plugging the inverses of the second and third relations in the fourth, you get

$$\frac{r-1}{2(1+k)r} + \frac{N-1}{2}\frac{q-1}{2(1+k)q} = \frac{N}{4}.$$

Multiply by $2(k+1)$ and expand,

$$1-\frac1r + \frac N2-\frac12-\frac N{2q}+\frac1{2q}= \frac{Nk}2+\frac N2.$$

Compare to the first,

$$\frac{1}{r} + \frac{N}{2q} -\frac{1}{2q} = \frac{1}{2}- \frac{kN}{2}.$$